# Is there a good way in Scala to interpret the types of values in a CSV

Tags: scala, parsing, csv, types

Suppose I'm given a CSV with the following values:

```
0, 1.00, Hello
3, 2.13, World
  .
  .
  .
```

Is there a good method or library that could automatically detect the best type to classify a given column as?  In this case (Int, Float, String).

For more context, I'm attempting to extend a CSV parsing library to allow it to report histogram like data on the CSV that is passed in.  The idea is to make it very easy to add certain validation tasks into this framework so as to figure out deficiencies or irregularities in a CSV data dump.

Intially I thought to write something which a user could supply a config file that specified the types, but for cases when the CSV column sets are very large, or just for ease of use, I'd like to attempt to automatically detect the types instead of having a user have to write them out.

Comment: This question repeats [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17126365/2483228) almost exactly.  Although the angle on automatic typing is potentially novel.

Answer (score 1):

One answer might be:

```
def parse(s:String): Any = Try(s.toInt) orElse(Try(s.toDouble)) getOrElse(s)
```

Then you can use pattern-matching to do whatever you want with it.

You could, of course, first do regular-expression tests on the string to see which type you have.  But I'm fairly sure just brute-forcing the parse for each format, as above, will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Consider parser combinators; inferred types are reported via a list of case classes,

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

trait CSVType
case class LiteralStr extends CSVType
case class Float extends CSVType
case class Integer extends CSVType
case class Bool extends CSVType
case class NA extends CSVType  // Not Available

class CSV extends JavaTokenParsers {   

  def row: Parser[List[CSVType]] = repsep(value, ",")

  def value: Parser[CSVType] =     
    floatingPointNumber ^^ { f => if (f.toDouble.toInt == f.toDouble) Integer() 
                                  else Float() } | 
    "NA"                ^^ { na => NA() } | 
    ("true" | "false")  ^^ { b => Bool() } |
    stringLiteral       ^^ { s => LiteralStr() } 


}


object ParseExpr extends CSV with App {
  println("in: "+ args(0))
  println(parseAll(row, args(0)))
}
```

Hence

```
scala> val s  = """1.23,2,true,NA,"hello" """
s: String = "1.23,2,true,NA,"hello" "

scala> ParseExpr.main(Array(s))
in: 1.23,2,true,NA,"hello" 
[1.24] parsed: List(Float(), Integer(), Bool(), NA(), LiteralStr())
```

Note that combinators include the parsing of types such as numerics, boolean and strings. In addition, custom types are defined by the parser, for instance `NA`. See [JavaTokenParsers trait](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/JavaTokenParsers.scala#L1) for definitions used here.

Each case class may include additional logic to report typing in a most convenient way.