# Read CSV in Scala into case class instances with error handling

Tags: scala, csv

I would like to read a CSV String/File in Scala such that given a case class `C` and an error type `Error`, the parser fills an `Iterable[Either[Error,C]]`. Is there any library that does this or something similar?

For instance, given a class and error

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

type Error = String
```

and the CSV String

```
Foo,19
Ro
Bar,24
```

the parser would output

```
Stream(Right(Person("Foo",1)), Left("Cannot read 'Ro'"), Right(Person("Bar", 24)))
```

UPDATE:

I think my question wasn't clear, so let me clarify: is there a way read CSV in Scala without defining boilerplate? Given **any** case class, is there a way to load it automatically? I would like to use it in this way:

```
val iter = csvParserFor[Person].parseLines(lines)
```

Comment: There is unlikely to be a library that does exactly this (and anyway, asking for a library recommendation is off-topic for SO). There are any number of CSV reading questions/answers already (e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126365/strongly-typed-access-to-csv-in-scala) so where are you stuck in implementing this yourself?

Comment: I just deleted the stuff here because the discussion was going a little off-rails, and we've got the relevant info below. I'm not 100% sure there was 'rudeness' involved, but that's a moot point, I think. The conversation entirely had run its course.

Comment: can we assume the case class contains only basic value types (Int,  Double) and Strings? If not, how will more complex types be encoded in the CSV? If you're after more general serialization/deserialization to csv, I suggest looking at scala-pickling and a CSV backend...

Comment: Yes, let's assume that the case class contains only basic values

Comment: Can you explain the use-case? Is the CSV file external, or was it created from serialising the case classes? If you're just serialising/deserialising, I suggest something like scala-pickling

Comment: I think the proposed API is not quite right. Really, all the stuff about reading CSVs, quoting etc is nothing to do with making a case class. So it should be enough to have a generic function that given an array of Strings, makes Either with an Right instance for an arbitary case class, or a Left with an error? I think that will require a macro, about which I currently know nothing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a Shapeless implementation that takes a slightly different approach from the one in [your proposed example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/308). This is based on some code I've written in the past, and the main difference from your implementation is that this one is a little more general—for example the actual CSV parsing part is factored out so that it's easy to use a dedicated library.

First for an all-purpose `Read` type class (no Shapeless yet):

```
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success, Try }

trait Read[A] { def reads(s: String): Try[A] }

object Read {
  def apply[A](implicit readA: Read[A]): Read[A] = readA

  implicit object stringRead extends Read[String] {
    def reads(s: String): Try[String] = Success(s)
  }

  implicit object intRead extends Read[Int] {
    def reads(s: String) = Try(s.toInt)
  }

  // And so on...
}
```

And then for the fun part: a type class that provides a conversion (that may fail) from a list of strings to an `HList`:

```
import shapeless._

trait FromRow[L <: HList] { def apply(row: List[String]): Try[L] }

object FromRow {
  import HList.ListCompat._

  def apply[L <: HList](implicit fromRow: FromRow[L]): FromRow[L] = fromRow

  def fromFunc[L <: HList](f: List[String] => Try[L]) = new FromRow[L] {
    def apply(row: List[String]) = f(row)
  }

  implicit val hnilFromRow: FromRow[HNil] = fromFunc {
    case Nil => Success(HNil)
    case _ => Failure(new RuntimeException("No more rows expected"))
  }

  implicit def hconsFromRow[H: Read, T <: HList: FromRow]: FromRow[H :: T] =
    fromFunc {
      case h :: t => for {
        hv <- Read[H].reads(h)
        tv <- FromRow[T].apply(t)
      } yield hv :: tv
      case Nil => Failure(new RuntimeException("Expected more cells"))
    }
}
```

And finally to make it work with case classes:

```
trait RowParser[A] {
  def apply[L <: HList](row: List[String])(implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, L],
    fromRow: FromRow[L]
  ): Try[A] = fromRow(row).map(gen. from)
}

def rowParserFor[A] = new RowParser[A] {}
```

Now we can write the following, for example, using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net):

```
case class Foo(s: String, i: Int)

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val reader = new CSVReader(new java.io.FileReader("foos.csv"))

val foos = reader.readAll.asScala.map(row => rowParserFor[Foo](row.toList))
```

And if we have an input file like this:

```
first,10
second,11
third,twelve
```

We'll get the following:

```
scala> foos.foreach(println)
Success(Foo(first,10))
Success(Foo(second,11))
Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "twelve")
```

(Note that this conjures up `Generic` and `FromRow` instances for every line, but it'd be pretty easy to change that if performance is a concern.)

Comment: What about `implicit fromRow` in `rowParserFor` method? How do we get it?

Answer (score 14):

[kantan.csv](http://nrinaudo.github.io/kantan.csv/) seems like what you want. If you want 0 boilerplate, you can use its  [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) module and write:

```
import kantan.csv.ops._
import kantan.csv.generic.codecs._

new File("path/to/csv").asCsvRows[Person](',', false).toList
```

Which, on your input, will yield:

```
res2: List[kantan.csv.DecodeResult[Person]] = List(Success(Person(Foo,19)), DecodeFailure, Success(Person(Bar,24)))
```

Note that the actual return type is an iterator, so you don't actually have to hold the whole CSV file in memory at any point like your example does with `Stream`.

If the shapeless dependency is too much, you can drop it and provide your own case class type classes with minimal boilerplate:

```
implicit val personCodec = RowCodec.caseCodec2(Person.apply, Person.unapply)(0, 1)
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author of kantan.csv.

Comment: Can it do more than 22 columns in the CSV (as that's the limit for case classes)?

Comment: @aa8y sure, provided you have a type in which to store it. If all columns are of the same type, say, `Int`, you could request a `List[Int]`, which supports arbitrary lengths. Heterogeneous data might require slightly more work - you might need to implement your own instance of `RowDecoder`, but that's really fairly trivial, it's essentially a `Seq[String] => A`, where `A` is the desired type.

Answer (score 6):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, it's possible to pattern match a `String`s by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
// case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val csv = "Foo,19\nRo\nBar,24".split("\n")
csv.map {
  case s"$name,$age" => Right(Person(name, age.toInt))
  case line          => Left(s"Cannot read '$line'")
}
// Array(Right(Person("Foo", 19)), Left("Cannot read 'Ro'"), Right(Person("Bar", 24)))
```

---

Note that you can also use `regex`es within the extractor.

It could help in our case to consider a row invalid if the age isn't an integer:

```
// val csv = "Foo,19\nRo\nBar,2R".split("\n")

val Age = "(\\d+)".r

csv.map {
  case s"$name,${Age(age)}" => Right(Person(name, age.toInt))
  case line @ s"$name,$age" => Left(s"Age is not an integer in '$line'")
  case line                 => Left(s"Cannot read '$line'")
}
//Array(Right(Person("Foo", 19)), Left("Cannot read 'Ro'"), Left("Age is not an integer in 'Bar,2R'"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using [product-collections](https://github.com/marklister/product-collections)

```
import com.github.marklister.collections.io._
import scala.util.Try
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val csv="""Foo,19
          |Ro
          |Bar,24""".stripMargin

class TryIterator[T] (it:Iterator[T]) extends Iterator[Try[T]]{
      def next = Try(it.next)
      def hasNext=it.hasNext
}

new TryIterator(CsvParser(Person).iterator(new java.io.StringReader(csv))).toList
res14: List[scala.util.Try[Person]] =
List(Success(Person(Foo,19)), Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 1 at line 2 => Ro), Success(Person(Bar,24)))
```

Apart from the error handling this gets pretty close to what you were looking for: `val iter = csvParserFor[Person].parseLines(lines)`:

`val iter = CsvParser(Person).iterator(reader)`