# discover type from CSV columns in scala

Tags: json, scala, csv, jackson, play-json

I want to read a generic CSV file with headers but unknown column number into a typed structure. My question is kind of the same as [Strongly typed access to csv in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126365/strongly-typed-access-to-csv-in-scala) but with the fact I would have no schema to pass to the parser...

Until now, I was using Jackson CSV mapper to read each row as a Map[String,String], and it was working well.

```scala
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

def genericStringIterator(input: InputStream): Iterator[Map[String, String]] = {

    val mapper = new CsvMapper()

    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    val schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema.withHeader

    val iterator = mapper
      .readerFor(classOf[Map[String, String]])
      .`with`(schema)
      .readValues[Map[String, String]](input)

    iterator.asScala
  }
```

Now, we need the field to be typed, so 4.2 would be a Double but "4.2" would still be a String.

We are using play-json everywhere in our project, and so I know JsValue already has a great type inference for generic stuff like that.

As paly-json it is based on Jackson too, I thought it would be great to have something like

```scala
import play.api.libs.json.jackson.PlayJsonModule


def genericStringIterator(input: InputStream): Iterator[JsValue] = {

    val mapper = new CsvMapper()

    mapper.registerModule(PlayJsonModule)

    val schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema.withHeader

    val iterator = mapper
      .readerFor(classOf[JsValue])
      .`with`(schema)
      .readValues[JsValue](input)

    iterator.asScala
  }
```

But when I try the former code, I get an exception :

```
   val iterator = CSV.genericAnyIterator(input(
      """foo,bar,baz
        |"toto",42,43
        |"tata",,45
        | titi,87,88
        |"tutu",,
        |""".stripMargin))

    iterator
      .foreach { a =>
        println(a)
      }
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: We should be reading map, something got wrong
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:165)
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:128)
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:123)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.nextValue(MappingIterator.java:277)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.next(MappingIterator.java:192)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
    at my.company.csv.CSVSpec$$anon$4.<init>(CSVSpec.scala:240)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

I don't care particulary to have a play-json JsValue in the end, any Json structure with generic typed field would be ok. Is there another lib I could use for that ? For what I found, all other libs are based on a mapping given to the CSV Reader in advance, and what is important for me is to be able to infer the type from the CSV.

Comment: An overkill for this situation but you can pull this off with Shapeless.

Comment: @sinanspd I'm not sure Shapeless could help here. [PureCSV](https://github.com/melrief/PureCSV) is based on shapeless but still need to declare the type that will be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was lazy to want to find something working out of the box :)
In fact it was easy to implement it myself.

I went looking to lib in other languages that does this infering (PapaParse in JS, Pandas in python), and discovered that they were doing a test-and-retry with priority to guess the types.

So I implemented it myself, and it works fine !

Here it is:

```scala
def genericAnyIterator(input: InputStream): Iterator[JsValue] = {

    // the result of former code, mapping to Map[String,String]
    val strings = genericStringIterator(input)

    val decimalRegExp: Regex = "(\\d*){1}(\\.\\d*){0,1}".r

    val jsValues: Iterator[Map[String, JsValue]] = strings.map { m =>
      m.mapValues {
        case "" => None
        case "false" | "FALSE" => Some(JsFalse)
        case "true" | "TRUE" => Some(JsTrue)
        case value@decimalRegExp(g1, g2) if !value.isEmpty => Some(JsNumber(value.toDouble))
        case "null" | "NULL" => Some(JsNull)
        case value@_ => Some(JsString(value))
      }
        .filter(_._2.isDefined)
        .mapValues(_.get)
    }
    jsValues.map(map => JsObject(map.toSeq))
  }
```

which does in a test

```
 it should "read any csv in JsObject" in new WithInputStream {

    val iterator = CSV.genericAnyIterator(input(
      """foo,bar,baz
        |"toto",NaN,false
        |"tata",,TRUE
        |titi,87.79,88
        |"tutu",,null
        |"tete",5.,.5
        |""".stripMargin))

    val result: Seq[JsValue] = iterator.toSeq

    result should be(Stream(
      Json.obj("foo" -> "toto", "bar" -> "NaN", "baz" -> false)
      , Json.obj("foo" -> "tata",  "baz" -> true)
      , Json.obj("foo" -> "titi", "bar" -> 87.79, "baz" -> 88)
      , Json.obj("foo" -> "tutu",  "baz" -> JsNull)
      , Json.obj("foo" -> "tete", "bar" -> 5, "baz" -> 0.5)
    ) )
  }
```